# jquery smooth scrolling in Chrome NOT in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to a fixed header on top of the page. So when the user scroll down, the header stay up on top. However this is only work in Chrome, FireFox and Opera which scrolls smoothly.

If you have a look the code below. Open with IE and Google Chrome. You will see the difference! The header must stay in the wrapper.

[Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/tbkdLy8q/)

I would like to know how to make the scrolling smooth when repositioning objects inside the div elements when set to absolute to keep it floating at the top of the box.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h2>Title Header</h2>        
    </header>
    Content page
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:relative;
}

#wrapper > p {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

}
#wrapper header {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper header h2 { margin:0 }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').scroll(function(e){
         $('header').css('top',parseInt($('#wrapper').scrollTop())+'px');
    });
 });
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use this CSS and remove the JS for cross-browser compatibility:

```
// same CSS...
#wrapper p {
    margin-top: 50px; //no positioning just a top margin
    z-index: 0;

}
#wrapper header {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position: fixed; // from absolute to fixed
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
}
//same CSS...
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tbkdLy8q/1/)

Comment: This also has the advantage of not covering up the body text.

Comment: @CalvinScherle Oh yeah! I didn't get you. :P

Comment: I managed to get the header to float and to appear as if in the wrapper by using clientWidth/clientHeight as they return the size without the scrollbar.thanks!